# Hidden Features of Google Guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

Google Guice provides some great dependency injection features.

I came across the **@Nullable** feature recently which allows you to mark constructor arguments as optional (permitting null) since Guice does not permit these by default:

e.g.

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, @Nullable Phone phone) {
    this.firstName = checkNotNull(firstName, "firstName");
    this.lastName = checkNotNull(lastName, "lastName");
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable

What are the other useful features of Guice (particularly the less obvious ones) that people use?

Comment: How is that a hidden feature?  It's in the best practices guide which is two clicks from the main page.

Comment: It's three actually, if you want to be pedantic about it...!

Answer (score 39):

None of 'em are intended to be hidden, but these are my favorite 'bonus features' in Guice:

- Guice can [inject a TypeLiteral<T>](http://publicobject.com/2008/11/guice-punches-erasure-in-face.html), effectively defeating erasure.
- [TypeLiteral](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) can do [generic type resolution](http://publicobject.com/2008/07/typeresolver-tells-you-what-listget.html): this tells you that `get()` on a `List<String>` returns an `Iterator<String>`.
- [Types](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Types.html) is a factory for implementations of Java's generic type interfaces.
- [Grapher](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Grapher) visualizes injectors. If your custom provider implements [HasDependencies](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/HasDependencies.html), it can augment this graph.
- [Modules.override()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Modules.html#override-com.google.inject.Module...-) is incredibly handy in a pinch.
- Short syntax for defining parameterized keys: `new Key<List<String>>() {}`.
- [Binder.skipSources()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#skipSources-java.lang.Class...-) lets you to write extensions whose error messages track line numbers properly.
- [The SPI](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/package-summary.html). [Elements.getElements()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/Elements.html#getElements-java.lang.Iterable-) breaks a module into atoms and [Elements.getModule()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/Elements.html#getModule-java.lang.Iterable-) puts them back together.
- If you implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in a `Module`, you can install that module multiple times without problem.

Answer (score 13):

I like how totally open the `Scope` interface is: basically, it's just a transformation from `Provider` to `Provider`.  (Okay, from `Key` and `Provider` to `Provider`)

Want some things to be basically Singleton, but re-read from the database every half hour?  It's easy to make a scope for that.  Want to run some requests in the background, and have a scope that means "all background requests started from the same HTTP request?"  It's relatively easy to write that `Scope` too.

Want to scope some `Key` on your server during tests so that it uses a separate instance for each test that you're running from a client?  (With the test passing the test id in a Cookie or extra HTTP parameter)  That's harder to do, but it's perfectly possible and so [someone's already written that for you](http://code.google.com/p/guiceberry/).

Yes, excessive abuse of `Scope` will cause Jesse to start hunting around for the stakes and garlic cloves, but its amazing flexibility can be really useful.

Answer (score 12):

One great feature of Guice is how easy it makes implementing method interceptors in any `Module`, using:

```
public void bindInterceptor(
    Matcher<? super Class<?>> classMatcher,
    Matcher<? super Method> methodMatcher,
    MethodInterceptor... interceptors);
```

Now, any method matching `methodMatcher` within a class matching `classMatcher` in that `Module`'s scope is intercepted by `interceptors`.

For example:

```
bindInterceptor(
    Matchers.any(),
    Matchers.annotatedWith(Retryable.class),
    new RetryableInterceptor());
```

Now, we can simply annotate any method with `@Retryable` and our `RetryableInterceptor` can 
retry it if it fails.