# Android Java Guice can't step debug into @Inject annotated functions

Tags: java, android, guice

After adding the main Guice and assisted jar files to my project in Intellij, I can no longer step debug into files that contain the @Inject annotation. Just including these two jars in my project with no changes to my source produces the a number of warnings:

"Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute."

for ClassEmitter, DebuggingClassWriter, EmitUtils, KeyFactory, ReflectUtils, Enhancer, MethodInterceptorGenerator, NoOp and FastClassEmitter.

My questions - how do I restore step debugging in annotated source files and how do I clear up these errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608638/what-techniques-do-you-use-to-debug-complex-guice-bindings) SO question delineates a couple of good debugging techniques to use when Guice isn't playing ball:

> I found the following two tips useful for debugging from [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2718802/403455)
>
> - [Grapher](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Grapher) visualizes injectors. If your custom provider implements
>     [HasDependencies](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/HasDependencies.html), it can augment this graph.
> - [Binder.skipSources()](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#skipSources%28java.lang.Class...%29) lets you to write extensions whose error messages track line numbers properly.
>
> [Binder.skipSources()](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#skipSources%28java.lang.Class...%29) is useful if you write generic binding helper
>   methods and Guice only reports the line number of the generic helper
>   method, but you (most likely) actually want the line number of the
>   caller one level up the stack instead.